# What is the difference between configuration of agent in 'Agents' tab and in 'Bake' tab Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

In Unity, when navigate to the Window > Navigation, I see that in both Agents tab and Bake tab have configuration for the agent. They are agent's radius, height, max slope and step height. Why they exist in both 2 above tabs?

Specifically, my map use terrain with different height and I have 2 agent types : Car and Airplane. I want my car only be able to move on plain, and the airplane should be able to move on everything : mountain, plain or water. When I change the max slope and drop height in Agent tab (tested on each agent type), nothing happen, but when I do it in Bake tab then press Bake, both Car and Airplane agent can move on everything. Could you please point out my wrong and tell me the correct way!

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave my worked solution for later comer.

I found this in the manual:

- NavMesh bake settings describe how all the NavMesh Agents are
  colliding or avoiding the static world geometry. In order to keep
  memory on budget and CPU load in check, only one size can be
  specified in the bake settings.
- NavMesh Agent properties values describe how the agent collides with
  moving obstacles and other agents.

This means that the settings in the agents tab are solely for agent-agent collision, not for movement through the world.

To have differently navigating agents, you would need multiple NavMeshes. If I am not mistaken, this seems to be possible with the [new NavMesh component](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/NavMeshComponents) workflow.